# Wireshark Data view

Tags: wireshark

I would like to view the data from the capture in plain text, but when I do the "Follow UDP Stream" all I see is:

..........x..7..L....7....
..7..Ver 6.41 Dec 21 2011...d..7..~PIN2Width...a..7..~PIN2Width=5......7..~ExtendFmt...
..7..~ExtendFmt=1......7..WorkCode......7..WorkCode=0...Z..7....s..7..

Does anyone know how to fully decode the data section of the capture so that I can read it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to view the data from the capture in plain text,

Not all data from a capture *is* plain text.

> Does anyone know how to fully decode the data section of the capture so that I can read it?

I've heard there's a program called "Wireshark" that does a pretty good job of it.  The middle pane of its display shows packet data as fully as it can.

Comment: The Details pane needn't be in the middle, see Edit / Preferences / Layout. Note Wireshark guesses the protocol/format of the data by looking at the port numbers; if you have a known protocol over an unusual port, rightclick the List-pane entry (or select it and click Analyze), choose DecodeAs..., identify the source/dest port that matters, and choose the protocol.